# How to show only terms by id or slug on edit-tags.php (custom taxonomy manage page) for a custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

How can I show only terms by id or slug on edit-tags.php (custom taxonomy manage page) for a custom taxonomy.

I am saving term_owner metadata to a table for each term and getting all terms' ids for a specific term_owner. Now I want to show only these terms on `edit-tags.php`.

I have tried `list_terms_exclusions` filter but seems it doses not work for `edit-tags.php?taxonomy={custom_taxonomy_name}` or I am missing something.

Can anyone help me with a working example?

Thanks you.

Comment: @mha When you ask *"How can I show only terms by id or slug"* would it mean the same to ask *"How can I filter terms by id or slug?"* As written I'm not sure if that is what you mean or not. Also, you can post the code you have but you are saying is not working?

Comment: I was about to respond, but yeah -- not cool, I'll pass.

Comment: @mha -  No worries, it can be non-obvious. Glad to have you on board.

Answer (score 2):

The `edit-tags.php` doesn't listen to any arguments except the `s` search query variable. If you want to do anything more advanced, you will have to hook into the `get_terms` filter.

Comment: Can you please help me how can I do that? Whit some code example?

Answer (score 0):

I have added these code to my theme function.php for my custom taxonomy "series".

```
add_filter('edited_terms', 'mysite_edited_terms');
function mysite_edited_terms($term_id) {
  if($_POST['taxonomy'] == 'series'): {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ($user->ID) {
      $terms = get_user_meta($user->ID,'users_terms_for_series');
      $terms = (empty($terms) ? $term_id : "{$terms},{$term_id}");
      update_user_meta($user->ID,'users_terms_for_series',$terms);
    }
  }
}
```

```
add_filter('list_terms_exclusions', 'my_list_terms_exclusions', 10, 2);
function my_list_terms_exclusions( $exclusions, $args ) {
  global $pagenow;
  if (current_user_can('can_manage_all_terms') && 
    $pagenow=='edit-tags.php?taxonomy=series') {
    $terms = get_user_meta($user->ID,'users_terms_for_series');
    $exclusions = " {$exclusions} AND t.ID NOT IN ({$terms})";
  }
  return $exclusions;
}
```

but nothing happened. This code is based on @MikeSchinkel. I think @Jan Fabry is right that the edit-tags.php doesn't listen to any arguments. But I dont no how to do that.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.